# How to extract apple's 1 billion countdown?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to figure it out for hours and i didn't success, This [Counter](http://www.apple.com/itunes/10-billion-app-countdown/) from Apple 1 billion downloads prize. doesn't use flash at all, only javascript and 0-9 images, which makes it really cool. Now after stackoverflow successed to extract google's pacman, can we do that?

P.S I can't even know if this is using prototype or scriptaculous since they're both included.

Comment: What do you mean by "extract"? Are you asking for help in deducing how it works, or do you want to decode the current value it is displaying?

Comment: I mean get it out of the page for other use & easy modification.

Comment: Get what out of the page? The value, or the script?

Comment: You should read this if you are interested in how this counter works.http://www.shanison.com/2012/02/26/how-apple-store-billion-download-counter-works/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is: `http://images.apple.com/global/scripts/downloadcounter.js`

```
StepTimingFunction = {
    timingFunctionForStepCount: function (a) {
        return function (b) {
            return ((b * (a - 1)) >> 0) / ((a - 1))
        }
    }
};
DownloadCounter = Class.create();
Object.extend(DownloadCounter.prototype, {
    initialize: function (a) {
        this._url = a;
        this.loadData();
        this._isCounting = true
    },
    setIsCounting: function (a) {
        this._isCounting = a
    },
    stop: function () {
        if (this._isCounting) {
            if (this._drawTimeout) {
                window.clearTimeout(this._drawTimeout)
            }
            this.setIsCounting(false);
            if (this._delegate && typeof this._delegate.counterDidStop === "function") {
                this._delegate.counterDidStop(this)
            }
        }
    },
    start: function () {
        if (!this._isCounting) {
            this.loadData();
            this.setIsCounting(true);
            if (this._delegate && typeof this._delegate.counterDidStart === "function") {
                this._delegate.counterDidStart(this)
            }
        }
    },
    isCounting: function () {
        return this._isCounting
    },
    _delegate: null,
    setDelegate: function (a) {
        this._delegate = a
    },
    delegate: function () {
        return this._delegate
    },
    loadData: function () {
        if (this._nextUpdateTimeout) {
            window.clearTimeout(this._nextUpdateTimeout);
            this._nextUpdateTimeout = null
        }
        var a = document.location.href.toString();
        a = a.replace(/.apple.com\/.*$/, ".apple.com");
        new Ajax.Request((a + this._url + "?r=" + Math.random()), {
            method: "get",
            onSuccess: this.dataRequestDidFinishLoading.bind(this)
        })
    },
    dataRequestDidFinishLoading: function (o) {
        var k = o.responseText.split("|"),
            n, d, j, g, l, h, b, f, e, m, a, i, c;
        localServerBasedReferenceTime = Date.parse(o.getResponseHeader("Date"));
        if (k.length === 3) {
            n = k[0].split(" ");
            d = n[1];
            date = n[0].split("-");
            this.setRate(parseInt(k[2]) / 3600000);
            l = date[0];
            g = date[1];
            j = date[2];
            a = Date.parse(g + " " + l + ", " + j + " " + d + " GMT-0700");
            e = new Date(a + 3600000);
            m = e.getTime() - a + 1000;
            this._nextUpdateTimeout = setTimeout(this.loadData.bind(this), m);
            if (typeof localServerBasedReferenceTime === "number") {
                this._lastReferenceTime = localServerBasedReferenceTime
            } else {
                b = new Date();
                this._lastReferenceTime = b.getTime()
            }
            f = this._lastReferenceTime - a;
            i = Math.floor(parseInt(k[1]) + f * (this._rate));
            this.setCurrentCount(i);
            this.setNeedsDisplayIfNeeded()
        }
    },
    setNeedsDisplayIfNeeded: function () {
        if (!this._drawTimeout) {
            this._drawTimeout = setTimeout(this.draw.bind(this), this._drawRefreshRate)
        }
    },
    setElement: function (c) {
        this._element = c;
        var b = this._element.getElementsByClassName("digitGroupSeparator");
        if (b.length > 0) {
            var a = b[0];
            this._element.removeChild(a);
            this.setDigitGroupSeparatorTemplateElement(a)
        }
        this._element.empty();
        this.createDigitElementsIfNeeded();
        this.setNeedsDisplayIfNeeded()
    },
    setDigitGroupSeparatorTemplateElement: function (a) {
        this._digitGroupSeparatorTemplateElement = a
    },
    _currentCount: 0,
    setCurrentCount: function (a) {
        if (a !== this._currentCount) {
            this._currentCount = a;
            this.createDigitElementsIfNeeded()
        }
    },
    digitTemplateElement: function () {
        if (!this._digitTemplateElement) {
            this._digitTemplateElement = document.createElement("span");
            $(this._digitTemplateElement).addClassName("digit");
            var a = document.createElement("div"),
                b = document.createElement("div"),
                c = document.createElement("div");
            $(a).addClassName("digitText");
            $(b).addClassName("digitImage");
            this._digitTemplateElement.appendChild(a);
            this._digitTemplateElement.appendChild(b);
            $(c).addClassName("digitImageElement");
            b.appendChild(c.cloneNode(true));
            b.appendChild(c)
        }
        return this._digitTemplateElement
    },
    createDigitElementsIfNeeded: function () {
        if (this._element && (!this._digitElements || this._digitElements.length !== this._currentCount.toString().length)) {
            this._element.empty();
            this._createDigitElements()
        }
    },
    _createDigitElements: function () {
        if (!this._digitElements) {
            this._digitElements = []
        }
        var e = 0,
            b = (this._maxCount && this._currentCount >= this._maxCount) ? this._maxCount.toString().length : this._currentCount.toString().length,
            c = document.createDocumentFragment(),
            a, h = this.digitTemplateElement(),
            g = this._digitGroupSeparatorTemplateElement,
            d = (this._maxCount && this._currentCount >= this._maxCount) ? String(this._maxCount) : String(this._currentCount),
            f;
        if (!g) {
            g = document.createElement("span");
            $(g).addClassName("digitGroupSeparator")
        }
        for (e = 0 + this._digitElements.length; e < b; e++) {
            a = h.cloneNode(true);
            f = parseInt(d.charAt(b - (e + 1)));
            a.lastChild.style.top = "-" + (f * (this._digitImageAnimationCount * this._digitImageHeight)) + "px";
            this._digitElements[e] = a;
            if (e > 0 && ((e) % 3 == 0)) {
                c.insertBefore(g.cloneNode(true), c.firstChild)
            }
            c.insertBefore(a, c.firstChild)
        }
        this._element.insertBefore(c, this._element.firstChild)
    },
    currentCount: function () {
        return this._currentCount
    },
    setRate: function (a) {
        this._rate = a
    },
    rate: function () {
        return this._rate
    },
    _drawRefreshRate: 50,
    _digitImageHeight: 38,
    setDigitImageHeight: function (a) {
        this._digitImageHeight = a
    },
    _digitImageAnimationCount: 6,
    setDigitImageAnimationCount: function (a) {
        this._digitImageAnimationCount = a
    },
    _maxCount: false,
    setMaxCount: function (a) {
        this._maxCount = a
    },
    draw: function () {
        window.clearTimeout(this._drawTimeout);
        this._drawTimeout = null;
        var h = this._drawRefreshRate,
            e, j, k, c, a, l, o, b, n, d, m, p = this._digitImageHeight * this._digitImageAnimationCount,
            g, f = this._digitElements,
            q;
        if (this._element) {
            m = String(this._currentCount);
            this._currentCount = this._currentCount + Math.floor(this._rate * h);
            if (this._delegate && typeof this._delegate.counterDidReachValue === "function") {
                this._delegate.counterDidReachValue(this, this._currentCount)
            }
            if (this._maxCount && this._currentCount >= this._maxCount) {
                this._isCounting = false
            }
            if (!this._isCounting) {
                return
            }
            e = (this._maxCount && this._currentCount >= this._maxCount) ? String(this._maxCount) : String(this._currentCount);
            j = e.length;
            k = j - 1;
            for (c = k; c >= 0; c--) {
                l = parseInt(e.charAt(c));
                o = parseInt(m.charAt(c));
                if (l !== o) {
                    if (!((k - c) < f.length)) {
                        this._createDigitElements()
                    }
                    a = f[k - c].lastChild;
                    if (a.___animating !== true) {
                        n = o * p;
                        if (l > o) {
                            b = l * p
                        } else {
                            b = (o + (10 - o) + l) * p
                        }
                        if (a.style.top !== (d = "-" + n + "px")) {
                            a.style.top = d
                        }
                        g = 1 + ((b - n) / this._digitImageHeight);
                        a.___animating = true;
                        q = new Effect.Move(a, {
                            x: 0,
                            y: (-1 * b),
                            duration: 0.4,
                            mode: "absolute",
                            transition: StepTimingFunction.timingFunctionForStepCount(g)
                        });
                        q.__element = a;
                        q.finish = function (i) {
                            if (window.removeEventListener) {
                                window.removeEventListener("unload", arguments.callee, false)
                            }
                            if (this.__element !== undefined) {
                                this.__element.___animating = false
                            }
                        };
                        if (window.addEventListener) {
                            window.addEventListener("unload", q.finish, false)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        this._lastReferenceTime = (this._lastReferenceTime + h);
        this.setNeedsDisplayIfNeeded()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a [JS counter](http://images.apple.com/global/scripts/downloadcounter.js) coupled with [CSS](http://images.apple.com/itunes/10-billion-app-countdown/styles/billionappcountdown.css).

Comment: And some [sprite images](http://images.apple.com/home/images/counter_filmstrip20110114.png).

Answer (score 1):

The hearth of the whole script is this single image: http://images.apple.com/itunes/10-billion-app-countdown/images/filmstrip.png

Now everything should be obvious.

1. HTML placeholder for a single digit:

   ```
   <div class="digit-placeholder"></div>
   ```
2. CSS that styles that placeholder:

   ```
   .digit-placeholder {
        /* Dimensions of a single "frame" */
        width: 50px;
        height: 75px;

        background-image: url(...);
        background-position: 0 0;
   }
   ```
3. To display digit `7` you just have to move background (`background-positon` property) to the following coordinates: `0 -2800px` (that's only an example). To display `8` move it to `0 -3400px`.
4. To create an animation (change from 7 to 8) you just have to move background from -2800 to -3400 with a step of 60 in some period of time (let's say 0.5 second).

All you have to do is to clone that several times (10 times for one billion) and compute that period of time for each digit.

Answer (score 0):

There's a file stored on the apple server which contains a count and a timestamp:

http://www.apple.com/autopush/us/itunes/includes/countdown.inc

That should give you a rough count.

Answer (score 0):

Before I go to bed:

```
var number = '';
$('.digitImage').each(function(i) {
    number += Math.abs($(this).position().top) / 618;
});
console.log(+number);
```

Now how long did that take? 3 minutes trying to figure out how do install a bookmarklet in chrome for injecting jQuery... 5 more minutes to get it working.